# Elastic Cloud Circuit_breaking_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

We recently upgraded our elastic cloud deployment from 6.8.5 to 7.9
After the upgrade we are seeing the following error time to time.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "circuit_breaking_exception",
        "reason" : "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [416906520/397.5mb], which is larger than the limit of [408420352/389.5mb], real usage: [416906520/397.5mb], new bytes reserved: [0/0b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=32399/31.6kb, in_flight_requests=0/0b, model_inference=0/0b, accounting=4714192/4.4mb]",
        "bytes_wanted" : 416906520,
        "bytes_limit" : 408420352,
        "durability" : "PERMANENT"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "circuit_breaking_exception",
    "reason" : "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [416906520/397.5mb], which is larger than the limit of [408420352/389.5mb], real usage: [416906520/397.5mb], new bytes reserved: [0/0b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=32399/31.6kb, in_flight_requests=0/0b, model_inference=0/0b, accounting=4714192/4.4mb]",
    "bytes_wanted" : 416906520,
    "bytes_limit" : 408420352,
    "durability" : "PERMANENT"
  },
  "status" : 429
}
```

This deployment consists of only one node with 1G memory. We would like to know the cause of this error. Is it due to the upgrade?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the circuit breaker is a protection that some request doesn't push your cluster over the limit of what it can handle — this is killing a single request rather than (potentially) the entire cluster. Also note that this HTTP request alone isn't too large, but it trips the `parent` circuit breaker — so this request on top of everything else would be too much.

The initial circuit breaker was already added in [6.2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/27116), but was tightened down further in [7.0.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/33125). I assume that's the reason why you are seeing this (more frequently) now.

You could change the [`indices.breaker.total.limit`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html), but this isn't a magic switch to get more out of your cluster. 1GB of memory might just not be enough for what you are trying to do.